# laravel belong to many not working -- "1048 Column 'purchase_id' cannot be null"

Tags: laravel, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to store multiple `purchaseCategory` using Laravel and Vue, but after clicking submit I am getting this error. How do I solve it?

```js
1048 Column 'purchase_id' cannot be null
```

In my Vue file I am getting the `purchaseCategory` like this:

```html
<select multiple v-model="purchaseCategory">
  <option
    v-for="purchaseType in purchaseTypes"
    :key="purchaseType.id"
    :value="purchaseType.id"
  >
    {{ purchaseType.purchaseType }}
  </option>
</select>
```

I have also created a table to join `purchases` and `purchase_types`:

```php
Schema::create('purchase_type_purchase', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('purchase_type_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('purchase_id');
    $table->primary(['purchase_type_id', 'purchase_id']);
    $table->foreign('purchase_type_id')->references('id')->on('purchase_types')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('purchase_id')->references('id')->on('purchases')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

In my `purchase.php` model I have:

```php
use HasFactory;

protected $guarded = [];

public function purchase_types()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(PurchaseType::class,'purchase_type_purchase', 'purchase_id', 'purchase_type_id');
}
```

In my `PurchaseType.php` model I have:

```php
class PurchaseType extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    
    public function purchases()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(purchase::class);
    }
}
```

In my controller I am storing the data like this:

```php
$data = new purchase;

foreach ($req->purchaseCategory as $value) {
    $data->purchase_types()->attach($value);
}
```

Comment: in which line are you getting the error?

Comment: when click submit .

the message is ---""SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'purchase_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `purchase_type_purchase` (`purchase_id`, `purchase_type_id`) values (?, 2))"
"

Comment: in the model's table, a field called `purchase_id` exists and must be filled. seems you aren't filling it and sql returns this exception

Comment: You do a `$data = new purchase;` and then try to `attach` to the new model without saving it

Comment: @apokryfos if I do a  `$data= purchase::find(12)`; then its storing the data. but how do I do it dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean dynamically? Your purchase object needs to be in the database before you associate relationships to it